# Can something be "very historic"?

Tags: phrase-usage

In the video [NASA Administrator Bridenstine Chats with Elon Musk of SpaceX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2t4l_yMStE) Bridenstine uses "very historic" three times out of four times near the beginning of the video:

- [the historic launch complex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxcHO.jpg)   `00:10`
- [is a very historic I would say not just](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJXEX.jpg)   `00:30`
- [but a very historic monument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk5kw.jpg)  `00:35`
- [at this very historic site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQAWR.jpg)   `01:26`

**Question:** Can something be "very historic"? If so, under what circumstances would its usage be appropriate?

---

This is a little amusing as it parallels an episode of an old ("historic?") US television show where the character of the president reads a NASA-prepared statement and then critiques it. Starting just after `02:36` in [The West Wing - Galileo V](https://youtu.be/Fvb1e4-YgRE?t=156):

> (President reading teleprompter:) Good morning I ‘m speaking to you live from the west wing of the Whitehouse. Today we have a *very unique* opportunity to take part live, in an *extremely historic* event which… whoa, boy!
>
> (Critiquing the statement to the NASA writer:) Unique means one of a kind, something can’t be very unique nor can it be extremely historic.

Comment: There may be other appropriate tags.

Comment: It's perfectly valid.  It implies something of great historic significance.

Answer (score 1):

Although Google search on "very historic" comes up with about 500K result, almost all seem colloquial (like how it's used in the video) and travel-related usage (as in "a very historic building").

Personally I would instead say "...but a historically significant monument..." (at 00:35).  Indeed, "historical significance" yielded 5 million results in Google.  It sounds more academic, cultured, and thoughtful.

"Historic moment" / "record breaking" is also appropriate to mark a significant day, as well as "medical/engineering breakthrough" to describe research-related significant advances.

In my opinion, all are better alternatives than "very historic".