# Sorkin's "Your imagination, like a child, will explode with unrestrained possibilities for adventure." Works so well despite feeling problematic; why?

Tags: speech, dialogue

I'm going to *somewhat but not completely* premise my question on the following:

1. the line is likely written or edited by Aaron Sorkin rather than Kevin Falls (*Galileo* West Wing Season 2 Episode 9 [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_West_Wing_(season_2)#Episodes), [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0745623/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt))
2. that Aaron Sorkin knows what they are doing and the line wasn't simply an accident

From [a transcript](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=31&keyword=galileo) (video clips: [1](https://youtu.be/Fvb1e4-YgRE), [2](https://youtu.be/Uh4DGUNWmiU))

> BARTLET: Say the name.
>
> C.J.: I said the name.
>
> BARTLET: Say it again. Your imagination, like a child, will explode with unrestrained possibilities for adventure.
>
> C.J.: [with gusto] Galileo V!
>
> BARTLET: You didn't say it right.

**Question:** "Your imagination, like a child, will explode..." seems off to me; my list of top ten things that explode doesn't include children, and yet only recently did it occur to me that this wonderful line seems to me to be incorrect or at least problematic.

Am I wrong? If not, why does it work so well despite this?

Comment: I couldn't find a cadence tag. Slightly related: [Can something be "very historic"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/490515/217285)

Comment: Aaron Sorkin's dialog is so rich you can listen without being sure what the fast and complex plot is about—on West Wing, Sports Night, and The Social Network. Look at it this way, dialog reflects speech, and that means run-on sentences, wrong in writing, but darn right in the way we talk, I'd say.

Comment: I don’t think it works well at all. Which is just one reason why this question — which seems anyway to fall into the realm of literary criticism — can only be answered by opinions.

Comment: It doesn’t work well at all. Better would be “child’s”. The author is striving for effect and whether it works or not is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You're right; children don't usually explode. (Even figuratively.) The intended meaning is presumably:

> Your imagination, like that of a child, will explode with unrestrained possibilities for adventure.

That can, of course, also be phrased as:

> Your imagination, like a child's, will explode with unrestrained possibilities for adventure.

It is very common in colloquial English to compare dissimilar things when the meaning would probably be understood by the audience. I can't comment on whether Sorkin wrote it as he did intentionally or not.